# Alternative to slow [LEFT JOIN + OR] without UNION?

Tags: performance, join, mysql-5.6, union, query-performance

I have a reasonably simple query that returns all purchases for a given user, searching by his government issued id. The document could be in two different tables.

The query using only left joins runs **extremely slow**, as in - 11 **minutes**.
And if instead of an "OR", I run two separate queries, joined by a `UNION`, they yield the same exact output in 4 seconds.
Although possible, it would be preferable to avoid using UNION, due to external factors¹.

Am I missing something obvious that's causing this huge disparity?
Is there a reasonable way to fix the LEFT-JOIN-only query so that it returns in less than, say, 10 seconds?

Standard query:

```sql
SELECT
  purchase.id
FROM
  purchase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user on purchase.buyer = user.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_documents on user.id = user_documents.user
  LEFT OUTER JOIN buyer_info on purchase.id = buyer_info.purchase
WHERE documents.value = '123' OR buyer_info.document = '123'
```

Example of UNION used:

```sql
SELECT
  purchase.id
FROM
  purchase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON purchase.buyer = user.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_documents ON user.id = user_documents.user
WHERE documents.value = '123'
UNION
SELECT
  purchase.id
FROM
  purchase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN buyer_info ON purchase.id = buyer_info.purchase
WHERE buyer_info.document = '123'
```

All fields used in all tables during the query are indexed fields.

PURCHASE and BUYER_INFO table: ~32 million records each.
USER table: ~16 million records.
USER_DOCUMENTS table: ~8 million records.

This is the simplified tables' descriptions:

```
PURCHASE
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default |
| id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | NULL |
| buyer | bigint(20) | YES | MUL | NULL |
```

```
USER
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default |
| id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | NULL |
```

```
USER_DOCUMENTS
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default |
| id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | NULL |
| USER | bigint(20) | NO | MUL | NULL |
```

```
BUYER_INFO
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default |
| id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | NULL |
| purchase | bigint(20) | NO | UNI | NULL |
| document | varchar(14) | YES | MUL | NULL |
```

I wasn't sure if this should be on StackOverflow or here, but I've read the Help Center and it mentioned `query-performance` is adequate here. Given that I've already gone through dozens of questions in StackOverflow while researching this and didn't found anything that helped, I thought this could be the right place.

I've already tried:

- Pushing predicates into the OUTER JOIN clause, to no avail;
- Removing two LEFT JOINs entirely and using WHERE EXISTS instead -- this helped but not nearly enough;
- Using inner joins where applicable -- also helped but again not even close.

---

1 - External Factor: legacy critical production codebase that builds that SQL would need vastly greater changes in order to implement that as an UNION.

---

**EDIT:** *addressing some of the comments*
Both queries work perfectly as far as correct data retrieval goes, including the query using UNION.

Also, **the UNION query is already fast enough** for our purposes.

The only reason why I would *prefer* to avoid it is because it would require way more changes in a production codebase to get working. (The queries here are vastly sanitized and oversimplified.)
(That's why **the very title says** `without UNION`)

*If that's the only sensible way to go*, then **we'll go for it**, but I don't understand why adding an "OR" breaks the performance so much, and I thought maybe there was something I was overlooking.

If we brake the first query into two, they each take 2,5 seconds to run. But make it a single query using an OR operator and suddenly it takes 11 minutes.

I was hoping to get a better understanding of why is that, and if it was possible to *fix* it.

Answer (score 1):

If you select from the results of a union all you will be able to filter the results you are looking for in a speedy fashion and only have to have a single where clause.

```
SELECT info.id
FROM
  (SELECT
    purchase.id
  FROM
    purchase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON purchase.buyer = user.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_documents ON user.id = user_documents.user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    purchase.id
  FROM
    purchase
  LEFT OUTER JOIN buyer_info ON purchase.id = buyer_info.purchase) info
WHERE info.document = '123'
```

Comment: As per question title and description, I can't use UNION at all. One of the reasons being the Java Hibernate that creates the query doesn't support it. The UNION query stated in the question already works nicely, I just couldn't use it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the WHERE predicates into the joins, and check that at least one of the joins match:

```
SELECT purchase.id
FROM purchase
LEFT JOIN user 
    on purchase.buyer = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_documents 
    on user.id = user_documents.user
   and user_documents.value = '123'  
LEFT JOIN buyer_info 
    on purchase.id = buyer_info.purchase
   and buyer_info.document = '123'
WHERE COALESCE(user_documents.value, buyer_info.document) IS NOT NULL
```

I assumed that documents.value should be user_documents.value.

Comment: I was optimistic to try this, but unfortunately it didn't do much to improve performance over our 'standard' query. Still ~10 minutes to run. =/